# Converting one variable based on the class variable

Tags: r

I have a dataset which I'm trying to manipulate. This requires me to transform the values of an attribute, wheeltype, based on the class cartype variable values, 1 and 2. However I can't seem to get this working properly.

Well I've some code written but its giving me an error: invalid factor level, NA generated.

```
for( i in 1:30) {
    if(mydata$cartype[i] == 1) {
         mydata$wheeltype[i] = 1   

     }

     else {
         mydata$wheeltype[i] = 0

     }
}
```

What I'm expecting here is that wheeltype attributes will be converted to 1 if the cartype is 1 and cartype of 2 will then set wheeltype attributes to 0. My current output changes the wheeltype attributes into NA. with "invalid factor level, NA generated" as the warning.

Comment: Sounds like you want `?ifelse`.

Comment: make sure all of your columns are not factors. if you try and add elements to a vector that is a factor you will get that error

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of options using the `dplyr` syntax (using mtcars data):

```
library(dplyr)

data("mtcars")

# ifelse
mtcars %>%
  as_tibble(rownames = "model") %>%
  mutate(wheeltype = ifelse(cyl == 6, 1, 0))

# case_when
mtcars %>%
  as_tibble(rownames = "model") %>%
  mutate(wheeltype = case_when(cyl == 6 ~ 1,
                               cyl == 4 ~ 2,
                               cyl == 8 ~ 3,
                               T ~ NA_real_))
```